# How can I set the Text of a DropDownList using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I have seen some answers on how to set the value for a dropdown using jQuery. However in my case, I want to know how to use jQuery to set the text for a dropdown.

This example uses jQuery to set the value for my dropdown:

```
  var trimvalue ="345";

  $("#Trim").val(trimvalue);
```

In my current code Logic, I want to set the displayed text as well, which I tried to do in this way:

```
var trimtext ="samsung";

$("#Trim").text(trimtext);
```

This is not a correct syntax. Please provide any suggestions on whether we can set the the text using jQuery or not.

Comment: Are you asking how to select an existing value from a dropdown or overwrite the text of the selected option?

Comment: There is no `text()` property of a `<select>`. You set the `.val()` property and the display text of the corresponding option will be displayed in the dropdown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to set the text with something like

```
$('#Trim option:selected').text(trimtext);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yzgbk1fj/:

Or if you mean to add it, perhaps:

```
$('#Trim').append($('<option />').text(trimtext)).val(trimtext);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yzgbk1fj/1/

Answer (score 0):

First Create a  html tag in your html page

```
<select id='sampleSelect'>
<select>
```

Second in your Jquery target the select function using an ID

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var trimtext ="samsung";
  $("#sampleSelect").append(
                            "<option value="+trimtext+">"+trimtext+"</option>"
                            );  
});
```

And if you have alot of values for your drop down use a For loop. Hope this help.